# Gunicorn max_requests for Production

Tags: python, gunicorn

Is there any effect on performance if I use gunicorn max_requests setting for production server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Depends. Restarting workers eats resources. But the price is not too high. On the other hand if you have memory leaks then it will allow you to save memory. Thus effectively increasing performance.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that this setting is the cause of a response time issue I have having. Baseline response time of one of my sites, measured locally, was about 20ms. This goes up to about 300ms on a worker restart, so yes, there is a performance impact.

As a result of this, I've upped my setting from a super-safe 10 to 100.